# Yii: start controller from another view

Tags: yii

In my app I have two different controllers for two different screens of the same app. While in one I want to set a button that drives you to the other one. (Is a mobile app and I want the interaction between two screens).

I am trying:

```
href='window.open(".CController::createUrl('/mobilechart').")
```

I generate this code in the initial controller that's why I use php concat, but it's not working. It executes the same controller so I get an error because I don't pass the variables.

It looks like it works (it gets the right url) using:

```
href='".CController::createUrl('../index.php/mobilechart')."'
```

but it never charger it keeps like loading info. When I go directly to the new controller view it works perfectly!

How can I do this??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also supply the name of the other controller -- otherwise how can Yii guess which controller you want to redirect to?

```
href='window.open(".CController::createUrl('mobilechart/index').")
```

Comment: I have tried loads of things. mobilechart is the name of the controller so I have tried: ../mobilechart and with the complete link with several things but it tries to execute the actual controller again!It just works without the window.open but then it takes hours loading and never charges the web page! Thx!!

Comment: @Lucia: And what's the action name for the mobilechart controller?

Comment: In the browser the link: http://localhost/fonto/index.php/mobilechart works perfectly! http://localhost/fonto/index.php/mobilechart/index works also!

Comment: It works perfectly now! It was a problem with a javascript in the controller, I don't know why it worked in the browser but not in the transition... but works both ways, with mobilechart/index and absoluteUrl! Thank you both!